# GitHub not Recognizing Differences in File Structure

Tags: github

I'm having an issue where GitHub is not seeing any difference between two branches when one clearly has more folders (containing different content). When I compare these changes in a PR, GitHub claims:

> "There isn't anything to compare".

What could be causing this?

It's important for my codebase to have consistent folders as I'm using Statamic framework which makes use of file structures and filenames. See attached images for the differences:

[image]
[image]

Comment: A merge request (or "pull request" in GitHub-ese) is a request that someone perform a three-way merge. As such, it involves *three* commits, not just the two: the *base* for the merge matters here too. The base needs to be related, by commit history (the only kind of history in a Git repository), to both branch-tips. When it isn't, you get this error.